Selenium automation - e-mail token
I will start automation with Selenium in Python. To log in to the platform, you must fill out a token, which is sent to Outlook. How do I have the automation enter my email and retrieve the access token?
I haven't started the project yet, but I just need help with this part of recovering the token

I suggest you to do some research first, try implementing it yourself and ask here if you are stuck. Good luck! :)
